# Access a cell directly in .csv file using C programming

Tags: c, csv

hey guys!
is there any way of directly accessing a cell in a .csv file format using C?
e.g. i want to sum up a column using C, how do i do it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'access'?  Do you want to just read or also be able to write to the cell?

Comment: Why does it have to be in C? You can do something like this with one line using a program like awk.

Comment: It is a text file, you can't fseek them.  Use a dbase.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easiest to use the `scanf`-family for this, but it depends a little on how your data is organized. Let's say you have three columns of numeric data, and you want to sum up the third column, you could loop over a statement like this: (`file` is a `FILE*`, and is opened using `fopen`, and you loop until end of file is reached)

```
int n; fscanf(file, "%*d,%*d,%d", &n);
```

and sum up the `n`s. If you have other kinds of data in your file, you need to specify your format string accordingly. If different lines have different kinds of data, you'll probably need to search the string for separators instead and pick the third interval.

That said, it's probably easier not to use C at all, e.g. perl or awk will probably do a better job, :) but I suppose that's not an option.

Comment: what if i have to sum up every column in the file individually? this is fine for one column, but what for every column? how would the "%*d,%*d,%d" expression change?

Comment: @confused; the '*' modifier tells scanf not to actually do a conversion. So if you need more columns, let's say first and third you'd do `fscanf(file,"%d,%*d,%d",&col1,&col3)`, and if you need all three, you get `fscanf(file,"%d,%d,%d",&col1,&col2,&col3)`.

Comment: thanks! and any idea how i can do this when the file is being appended in real time? i am accessing the file repeatedly after a fixed interval, meanwhile data is continuously being added to the file resulting in more rows and columns!

Comment: @confused; this is trickier, as you need to worry about a lot of corner cases, such as the buffering behavior of the writer, or log rotation. Are you sure you have to do this in C? Slapping `tail -F` together with `awk` sounds a lot more promising.

Comment: have to do it in C. no option there!

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use C: read the entire line to memory, go couting "," until you reach your desired column, read the value and sum it, go to next line.

When you reach your value, you can use sscanf to read it.

Comment: Works fine unless and until a field contains ','. The RFC calls for double quoting to group fields that may contain commas. Details, details. Of course, often people saying CVS mean a simple format in which the fields *may not* contain a comma. In that case this really is the easy way, but you might consider using `strsep` if your libc includes it.

Comment: wouldnt parsing the whole file row by row to reach the desired value in every row (one column of the file) would have too much overhead? and i have hugeeeee files to read from. can't i read by giving address/location of the cell i want, like row2,col3? can that be done in C?

Comment: confused: The problem is because you do not have a rule for skipping fields, so you need to read each field to determine where a field ends. Also you cannot simple skip to next line, because you do not know where it starts, you need to keep reading the entire line to find its end. If you simple need one column, you can try to do a brute force and hacked code, simple read until you reach the column, read its data and goes reading until you find a line end, repeat again. But in my experience, I would do a parser that can read any column, because it's common to have to read more columns later :).

Comment: dmckee: good point about the ','. Fortunately all the files that I have worked one never had one so we never considered it. They were just simple fields values.

Comment: oh, ok, thanks! i was hoping there would be another way rather than parsing the whole file! sounds exhausting for the poor computer :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start by looking at [RFC 4180: Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), and then looking for implementations of the same. (Be aware though, that the notion of comma separated values predates the RFC and there are many implementations that do not comply with that document.)

I find:

- [ccsv](https://github.com/fauna/ccsv)

And not many others in plain c. There are quite a few c++ implementations, and most of the are probably readily adapted to c.